# What is the purpose of ignorePath

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bower-install

What is the purpose of

```
ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
```

in bowerInstall's configuration in yeoman's generator-angular?

Asking because it ruined my day when I included in the project a dependency module that I built with paths like 'app/scripts/app.js'. It just omitted the 'app/' part.